# Netty - Channel instantly closed

Tags: java, netty

I've started working with netty and (obviously) want to send messages between clients and server. Since I am in early stage, I have problems with the simple stuff, in this case it's sending a message. This is how I create my server and my client:

Client:

```
public void run() throws Exception
{
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try
    {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new SecureChatClientInitializer());
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        // Start the connection attempt.
        ChannelFuture future = b.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        Channel ch = future.awaitUninterruptibly().channel();
        ch.writeAndFlush("hi\r\n");

        // Wait until all messages are flushed before closing the channel.
        if (lastWriteFuture != null)
        {
            lastWriteFuture.sync();
        }
    } finally
    {
        // The connection is closed automatically on shutdown.
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public void run() throws InterruptedException
{
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try
    {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new SecureChatServerInitializer(sessionManager));
        b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
        b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } finally
    {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Client Initializer:

```
public class SecureChatClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>
{

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
    {
           ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        SSLEngine engine =
                SecureChatSslContextFactory.getClientContext().createSSLEngine();
        engine.setUseClientMode(true);
        pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
                8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new SecureChatClientHandler());
    }
}
```

Server Initializer:

```
public class SecureChatServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>
{

    ...

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
    {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        SSLEngine engine =
                SecureChatSslContextFactory.getServerContext().createSSLEngine();
        engine.setUseClientMode(false);
        pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(
                8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new SecureChatServerHandler(sessionManager));
    }
}
```

As you may have guessed from seeing the source code: Yes, parts of it are from the SecureChatExample. I edited parts of it and don't understand why it isn't working anymore. When executing the client, I only get one line of error message:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only call `group.shutdownGracefully();` when you actually want to exit the client. If you remove that line from your client, the `Channel` will remain open.

Also, you just need to suffix `\n` at the end of all messages sent.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that, you could close the channel like this:

```
  @Override
  public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.channel().pipeline().remove(this);
  }
```